# MySQL Query to select between 2 dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Table 'Notification_details' where I query to obtain the unique records with the following MySQL query

[image]

> select userid, max(notification_date) as notification_date from
>   notification_details group by userid order by notification_date asc

Which gives the result, where the userid is unique and the notification_date is the latest( max).
Now, I would like to extend the MySQL command to query between 2 dates of the result I have obtained :

[image]

Any idea, how to extend the above MySQL command ?

Comment: +1 for images, it explains better your situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I didn't missunderstand you:

```
SELECT alias.* 
FROM (select userid, max(notification_date) as notification_date from notification_details group by userid order by notification_date asc) alias
WHERE alias.notification_date BETWEEN DATE1 AND DATE2
```